# Get text from select in table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using either raw javascript or jQuery, I need to get the text from a select that is in a table cell.  I have attached the code that I have gotten to work and almost get me what I need.

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('tblHours');
var rowCount = tbl.rows.length;
var colCount = tbl.rows[0].cells.length;

for (var i = 0;i<rowCount;i++) {
    var myrow = tbl.rows[i];
    for (var j=0;j<colCount;j++) {
        alert(myrow.cells[j].firstChild.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is it gets me the raw html for the select, and I need to know what text is actually selected.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the html of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to jquery!

```
var tbl = $('#tblHours');

tbl.find('tr').each(function(){
   $(this).find('td').each(function(){
       alert($(this).find('select :selected').val());
   });
});
```

I didnt test code. Just for example.

Comment: Wow that was fast!  I will try the code now and see what happens.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if you try stripping html from it by this function or just use the code from it

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
}
```

Comment: oh ok can you post whats your alert output

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0;i<$('#tblHours tr').length;i++) {
    var myrow = $('#tblHours').find('td');
    for (var j=0;j<myrow .length;j++) {
        alert(myrow.text());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the selected option in HTML select refer to : http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Try this code (not tested):

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('tblHours');
var rowCount = tbl.rows.length;
var colCount = tbl.rows[0].cells.length;

for (var i = 0;i<rowCount;i++) {
    var myrow = tbl.rows[i];
    for (var j=0;j<colCount;j++) {
        alert($(myrow.cells[j]).find('select :selected'));
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked just as well :)  Only reason I went with the other is that it doesn't combine raw and jQuery.  Thanks for your input!